# How do I debug zsh when startup performance is slow?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, iterm, zsh

I'm using Z shell inside iTerm2 every time I open up a new window or a new tab it takes around 8 - 9 seconds to load.

I found some information on how to debug zsh. I came across this [Speeding Up My Shell](https://blog.mattclemente.com/2020/06/26/oh-my-zsh-slow-to-load/) also I've found a script on [SPEEDING UP ZSH AND OH-MY-ZSH](https://blog.jonlu.ca/posts/speeding-up-zsh).

Running the script I get this

```bsh
╰─❯ for i in $(seq 1 10); do /usr/bin/time /bin/zsh -i -c exit; done
        1.56 real         0.76 user         0.47 sys
        1.30 real         0.74 user         0.44 sys
        1.31 real         0.74 user         0.44 sys
        1.30 real         0.74 user         0.44 sys
        1.31 real         0.74 user         0.44 sys
        1.31 real         0.74 user         0.44 sys
        1.30 real         0.74 user         0.44 sys
        1.29 real         0.74 user         0.44 sys
        1.31 real         0.75 user         0.44 sys
        1.31 real         0.74 user         0.44 sys
```

I'm using the antigen plugin.

Any idea what is adding another 5 - 6 seconds. How can I debug this?

Comment: I would rename all your startup zsh files so you have none, then add the command you need back one by one

Comment: @mmmmmm Thanks for responding. I've commented out everything in my `~/.zshrc` file. Then restarted the OS (just in case something is cached). I'm still getting 8 seconds on new window and new tab.

Comment: and ~/.zshenv and ~/.zprofile and ~/.zlogin ? Ans what is the command called by iTerm, does Terminal.app show the same?

Comment: @mmmmmm when I open the Terminal.app I can see its switching between bash -> systemctl -> uname in a loop see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bufi1w4j8youiim/2022-02-24-18-16-40.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: What is your default shell? Try iTem but edit the command tp `/bin/zsh -l` as that should be the one that is the default

Comment: @YuriGurin What fancy enhancement did you install?  Remove it.

Comment: @MarcWilson I've disabled all extensions. I still get the same result see my previous comment

Comment: @YuriGurin Obviously, you have not, as is obvious from your MP4.  Remove everything you have added to the startup, or move them elsewhere.

Comment: I would manually run a `zsh -i -l -x`, and observe where an unusual amount of time has been eaten. Note that the `-x` will slow down the startup even more, but at least you see what's going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found the problem. The issue was not directly related to `.zshrc` as commenting out the entire file gave me the same results. It was clear to me that the issue was happening before `.zshrc` was loaded. My advice to anybody with a zsh issue look at all the [components of zsh](https://dev.to/jasmin/how-to-manage-zsh-startup-files-with-correct-settings-pkf). From the article my guess is it was either `.zlogin` or `.zprofile`. zlogin was empty whereas `.zprofile` had over 2000 lines of `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`. Deleting everything in `.zprofile` fixed the issue for me, however moments later duplicate commands have again reappeared. In my `.zshrc` the issue was this:

```bsh
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/[your-user-name]/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

which I have replaced with

```bsh
#echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/[your-user-name]/.zprofile
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

I have no idea why homebrew had this config in my `.zshrc` file, however, I have come across other users that have had this issue see https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/446#discussioncomment-1084000

Comment: Very nice find. Any chance you can document the startup times on your Mac after fixing / optimizing the dot files?

Comment: I've been struggling with this issue for so many years, and after a new attempt at solving this I came across your finding. I cannot believe how weird this issue is, but thanks!